# Checkout another repository in azure pipelines yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

Well, I have the following code that uses a template file in azure Devops:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: "Framework Back-end/templates-devops"

extends:
  template: azure-pipelines-template.yml@templates
```

This works very well, downloading yml file from another project inside same organization. But inside my "azure-pipelines-template.yml" I'm trying to do the following:

```
  - job: Deploy
    pool: ${{parameters.agent}}
    displayName: Deploy on Kubernetes
    dependsOn: Push
    condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master', 'main', 'qas', 'develop'))
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: templates
```

But I got the error:

```
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier templates-devops does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://xx@xx/xxx/Framework%20Back-end/_git/templates-devops/' not found
```

I need to make a checkout because in other steps I will need to use the files that exist in "template-devops" repository. I can't understand why my pipeline can download the "azure-pipelines-template.yml" file but can't checkout the repository.

**SOLVED**

Was a permission problem in Settings , I **disabled** the flags:

Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines

Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines

Comment: Quick note: These above settings must be updated in the Project where the pipeline is being run. And the Last one still can be enabled which worked for me.

Comment: Service connection required for other project repo.

Comment: If that project is in a separate Azure DevOps organization, you'll need to configure a service connection of type Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server with access to the project and include that in YAML, in the `endpoint` property

Answer (score 0):

I create a demo to reproduce your environment, but it works well on my side. The checkout step works well. Here is my yaml file and temp file:

**Main.yaml**

```
resources:
  repositories:  
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: MyAgile TestPro/yaml

pool:
  name: 'default'


extends:
  template: azure-pipelines-template.yml@templates
```

**Temp.yaml**

```
  stages:
    - stage: 
      jobs:
        - job: Deploy
          steps:
            - checkout: self
            - checkout: templates
            - task: PowerShell@2
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  # Write your PowerShell commands here.
                  
                  Write-Host "Hello World MyAgileTestPro temp"
```

My test result:
[image]

At present, we recommend you can check if your account has the project admin level for your project Framework Back-end. And please check if there is any name changed about your project.